# Troubleshooting TL071 to TA8207 100 Hertz hum

Tags: noise, ground, preamp

I worked out to build a pre-amplifier connected to a power driver in a single setups(a pcb). Problem arises when it's powered up. here are a few questions.

- Setup has a **TL071CP** as preamp with a *unity* gain. an input impedance of **10meg** through a 100n polyester cap. no mistery here. To notice: we used single star-gnd. Vcc is 12 volt not 17.5 as intended or 35 volts as preferred by the JFET.
- Output stage is politely recycled **7W** beautiful amplifier device from Toshiba Microelectronics division tagged **TA8207K**. Actually using 5% resistors at the gain configuration at 100 ohms. All the setup follows guidelines from the schematic.

These are close to original schematics next,
[image]
[image]

**Tests:**

- I've tested *1meg* and *2meg* input impedance but decided later 10meg as Zin.
- For the medium drive Zin tested several passive devices. in general the **TA8207** has a 35kohm Ain Z. Ran it using 2.2k resistor to ground and seems to be nice but not completely noise-free at the speakers.
- Thus replaced original 47kohms Ain Z at the driver for a 2.2k/2.2k which has a noticeable gain and frequency response along with noise again.
- Then finally tried floating Ain to Vcc/2 with no success. In exchange used the voltage divider at **TA78207**'s Ain.

**Goals:**

My idea is having 3/10 from the actual noise without rebuilding everything. Ideally replacing 5% to 1% bleeder hum noise filter.
**Main question:**

- Do i need matching the output impedance from **TL071** which is 120kohm at 10meg input Z to the 35kohm Z in JFET related equation i haven't read?. I've considered a bleeder notch-filter very likely solution to 100hz hum.
- If i float using Vcc/2 or add an inductors or add resistors at the different grounds. still need a notch-filter and Vcc/2 at all Ains. ?

Thank you for all your comments. Diego

Comment: What is the noise, what frequency, and do you have a schematic, and or board image?

Comment: For amplifiers like this, you do not need impedance matching, you actually do not want it. You want your output stages to have a Z << the input to the next stage. That way the Z of the next stage does not load the output.

Comment: What device is plugging into this, if you have 10M input resistors on the JFET you will have a lot of noise. You could try making a 50 or 100 hz notch filter and putting it after your pre amp. Do you have any frequencies around that range?

Comment: Gain is the ratio of output to input. You mean **unity** gain - not "zero" gain. "Zero drift" also has a specific meaning in electronics.

Comment: also if your system is being powered off of an isolated source such as a 24 volt DC supply. You don't need to tie the AC ground to the ground on your DC supply. That could be a huge source of your noise.

Comment: Sure i catch the idea MadHatter. DC supply  is likely fine isolated. 10M ran fine for a while. whole room is 50hz noisy for several reasons included power lines next to the window. but when all the setup was tied together noise tripled. adding a near 50hz notch filter would be fine. i can deal with that but understanding where the current noise is flowing at the preamp would be ideal. eventually not filtering out output but 50hz at the gain bleeder resistor. is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be power line, or rectified power from transformer, coupling by electrostatic field into the (+) pin of TLO 71.

Or could be magnetic field of power line or of diode surge currents, coupling into a LOOP or into multiple LOOPS of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Your 220VAC is at 50Hz, not 100Hz. Did you measure the hum frequency?
The 100Hz might be the 12VDC with rectified hum on it that passes into the preamp input bias voltage divider. The voltage divider should be fed from an RC filter with 1k in series and 100uF to ground.
Of course the input cable from the signal source and the cable from the output of the preamp to the amplifier input must be shielded audio cables to reduce 50Hz pickup.
What is the signal source that needs such a high input impedance? This very high input impedance might pickup rectified power supply hum from nearby wiring or transformer.